# Function calling trouble

Tags: c

Still trying to grasp how to organize syntax. I have a an exercise where I need write a program that calls the function and interacts with the user where they enter a year and the population is the output. I am unsure as whether I am on the right track.

Here's what I have:

```
/*Calculate Gotham's population*/

#include <stdio.h>

int get_population (int , double );

int main (void){
    int t; 
    double population;

    printf("Enter a year after 1990 >  ");
    scanf("%d", &t);

    population = int get_population (t);

    printf("Predicted Gotham City population for 2015 (in thousands):%f");

    return 0;
}

int get_population (int t, double P){
    double P = 52.966 + 2.184*t;
    return P;

    printf("Predicted Gotham City population for 2015 (in thousands):%d");
}
```

Comment: population = int get_population (t); <= You don't need the "int" here, also you're assigning the results of a function that returns an int to a double.

Comment: I'm pretty sur this won't compile. What is this `int` in line `population = int get_population (t);`? Also the printf in the function get_population() is unreachable. And you name the parameter of your function like a local variable (`P`).

Comment: isn't the int the function type

Comment: You seem to be confused about whether or not to define `get_population()` so as to take 1 input or 2. You declare it as a function that takes 2 but your main is trying to call it as if it took just 1 input. You probably want to drop `P` as an input parameter -- move it to a local variable in the function definition.

Comment: So I need to change main then

Comment: You need to change a number of things, including main.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need two arguments in method `get_population`. You only need to pass the `year` to it and it should return the calculated population value.

Also calling the method and setting it's returned value to a variable also not done properly.

No need of `printf` in `get_population` method as it won't be executed coz control will return from the method before it.

Change your code as following.

```
int get_population (int);

int main (void){
    int year; 
    double population;

    printf("Enter a year after 1990 >  ");
    scanf("%d", &year);

    population = get_population (year);

    printf("Predicted Gotham City population for %d (in thousands):%f", year, population);

    return 0;
}
int get_population (int year){
    double population = 52.966 + 2.184* year;
    return population;
}
```

Comment: @gsamaras I updated the answer with explanation. Please let me know if I need to add anything more. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, that make sense.

Comment: Generally, printed messages should end with a newline.  The prompt message ("Enter …") is an exception; the user's input provides a newline there.

Answer (score 1):

Some things were already explained in the other answer, this is just a different approach.

Annotated original code:

```
/*Calculate Gotham's population*/

#include <stdio.h>

//Your population calculation depends on the year only, so you only need one argument
int get_population (int , double );

int main (void){
    int t; 
    double population; //Can a not natural number of people exist? An int is better suited for this

    printf("Enter a year after 1990 >  ");
    scanf("%d", &t);

    //There is no need to cast the return of the function
    //Also a cast to another type would be done by enclosing it with brackets
    //Example: population = (int) get_population(t);
    population = int get_population (t);

    printf("Predicted Gotham City population for 2015 (in thousands):%f");

    return 0;
}

int get_population (int t, double P){
    double P = 52.966 + 2.184*t;
    return P;
    //The following code will not be executed, since the function has ended
    printf("Predicted Gotham City population for 2015 (in thousands):%d");
}
```

Following is how I'd 'fix' your code:

```
/*Calculate Gotham's population*/

#include <stdio.h>
//Since the function only depends on the year, only 1 argument is needed
int get_population (int);

int main (void){
    //Since a not natural number of people can't exist, using ints
    int year, population;

    printf("Enter a year after 1990 >  ");
    scanf("%d", &year);

    //Calling the function that our code knows returns an int and assigning it to a variable
    population = get_population (year);

    //To use variables in a printf, you'll use the '%' followed by a description( %d for (decimal) int, %c for char, %s for strings,...)
    //And add those variables, in the right order, at the end
    printf("Predicted Gotham City population for %d (in thousands):%d", year, population );

    return 0;
}

//Since you only do the same thing every time, you can just return the calculation
int get_population (int year){
    return (52.966 + 2.184*year);
}
```

If you understand the changes, maybe try adding some fail-safe tests, maybe output another text if the input year is < 1990.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the helpful explanations.

Comment: Generally, printed messages should end with a newline.  The prompt message ("Enter …") is an exception; the user's input provides a newline there.